Bathtub vortex simulation with Mathematica FEM
Bathtub vortex is well known phenomena that can be simulated with numerical methods like FDM described here and FEM described in our paper here. Let consider bath with 2 inlets and one outlet in a form of square tube. In this picture we show only one inlet velocity profile at $x=-5$, and second one at $x=5$ has opposite velocity
reg = RegionUnion[Cuboid[{-5, -1.5, 0}, {5, 1.5, 1}], 
  Cuboid[{-.5, -.5, -5}, {.5, .5, 0}]]; {Graphics3D[{{LightBlue, 
    Opacity[.5], Cuboid[{-5, -1.5, 0}, {5, 1.5, 1}]}, {Blue, 
    Opacity[.5], Cuboid[{-.5, -.5, -5}, {.5, .5, 0}]}}], 
 Plot3D[(1 - (2 y/3)^2) (1 + Tanh[50 (z - 3/4)])/2, {y, -1.5, 
   1.5}, {z, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Mesh -> None, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotPoints -> 50, 
  AxesLabel -> {"y", "z", "u"}]} 


To simulate flow, we use nonlinear FEM as follows:
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
AbsoluteTiming[\[Nu] = 1/65; Fr = 0.4; {U, V, W, P} = 
    NDSolveValue[{{(-\[Nu])*Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][p][x, y, z] + u[x, y, z]*D[u[x, y, z], x] + 
         v[x, y, z]*D[u[x, y, z], y] + w[x, y, z]*D[u[x, y, z], z], (-\[Nu])*Laplacian[v[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][p][x, y, z] + 
         u[x, y, z]*D[v[x, y, z], x] + v[x, y, z]*D[v[x, y, z], y] + w[x, y, z]*D[v[x, y, z], z], (-\[Nu])*Laplacian[w[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + 
         Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][x, y, z] + u[x, y, z]*D[w[x, y, z], x] + v[x, y, z]*D[w[x, y, z], y] + w[x, y, z]*D[w[x, y, z], z], 
        Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][x, y, z] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][v][x, y, z] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][w][x, y, z]} == {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
      {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == (1 - (2*(y/3))^2)*((1 + Tanh[50*(z - 3/4)])/2), v[x, y, z] == 0, w[x, y, z] == 0}, 
        x == -5 && 0 <= z <= 1], DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == (-(1 - (2*(y/3))^2))*((1 + Tanh[50*(z - 3/4)])/2), v[x, y, z] == 0, 
         w[x, y, z] == 0}, x == 5 && 0 <= z <= 1], DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == 0, v[x, y, z] == 0, w[x, y, z] == 0}, -5 < z < 0], 
       DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == 0, v[x, y, z] == 0, w[x, y, z] == 0}, Abs[y] == 1.5], 
       DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == 0, v[x, y, z] == 0, w[x, y, z] == 0}, z == 0 && Abs[x] >= 0.5 && Abs[y] >= 0.5], 
       DirichletCondition[{p[x, y, z] == 0, w[x, y, z] == 0}, z == 1], DirichletCondition[p[x, y, z] == -(Fr^2)^(-1), z == -5]}}, {u, v, w, p}, 
     Element[{x, y, z}, reg], Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, w -> 2, p -> 1}, 
       "MeshOptions" -> {AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.002}}]; ]

This code is relatively fast, and as result we have flow that is not balanced with inlet and outlet flow rates
out = -NIntegrate[
    W[x, y, z], {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}, {z, -5, 0}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 2]/5

(*Out[]= 1.5242*)

in = 
 2 NIntegrate[U[-5, y, z], {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 2]

(*Out[]= 0.99595*)

We see that averaged flow rate in a square tube in 1.52 times more than in inlets. To balance flow, we make next step
AbsoluteTiming[u0 = out/in; {U, V, W, P} = 
    NDSolveValue[{{(-\[Nu])*Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][p][x, y, z] + u[x, y, z]*D[u[x, y, z], x] + 
         v[x, y, z]*D[u[x, y, z], y] + w[x, y, z]*D[u[x, y, z], z], (-\[Nu])*Laplacian[v[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][p][x, y, z] + 
         u[x, y, z]*D[v[x, y, z], x] + v[x, y, z]*D[v[x, y, z], y] + w[x, y, z]*D[v[x, y, z], z], (-\[Nu])*Laplacian[w[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + 
         Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][x, y, z] + u[x, y, z]*D[w[x, y, z], x] + v[x, y, z]*D[w[x, y, z], y] + w[x, y, z]*D[w[x, y, z], z], 
        Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][x, y, z] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][v][x, y, z] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][w][x, y, z]} == {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
      {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == u0*(1 - (2*(y/3))^2)*((1 + Tanh[50*(z - 3/4)])/2), v[x, y, z] == 0, w[x, y, z] == 0}, 
        x == -5 && 0 <= z <= 1], DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == (-u0)*(1 - (2*(y/3))^2)*((1 + Tanh[50*(z - 3/4)])/2), v[x, y, z] == 0, 
         w[x, y, z] == 0}, x == 5 && 0 <= z <= 1], DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == 0, v[x, y, z] == 0, w[x, y, z] == 0}, -5 < z < 0], 
       DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == 0, v[x, y, z] == 0, w[x, y, z] == 0}, Abs[y] == 1.5], 
       DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == 0, v[x, y, z] == 0, w[x, y, z] == 0}, z == 0 && Abs[x] >= 0.5 && Abs[y] >= 0.5], 
       DirichletCondition[{p[x, y, z] == 0, w[x, y, z] == 0}, z == 1], DirichletCondition[p[x, y, z] == -(Fr^2)^(-1), z == -5]}}, {u, v, w, p}, 
     Element[{x, y, z}, reg], Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, w -> 2, p -> 1}, 
       "MeshOptions" -> {AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0011}}]; ]

This code takes 8 times more time than that code above, but as result we have nice vortex in the tube
Table[StreamDensityPlot[{U[x, y, z] , V[x, y, z]} // 
   Evaluate, {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> z, Frame -> False, PlotRange -> All], {z, -5, 0, 1}] 


The question is that this flow is also not balanced in the flow rate of inlet and outlet:
out = -NIntegrate[W[x, y, -5], {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 2]

(*Out[]= 1.43719*)

in = 
 2 NIntegrate[U[-5, y, z], {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 2]

(*Out[]= 1.56518*)

It is not entirely clear why nonlinear FEM produces such a solution with not balanced flow rates of inlet and outlet. It is also not entirely clear why this imbalance can be reduced in 2 steps above.
